# How to get timestamp using Object id in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

how can I get timestamp using object id in MongoDB.I am using NodeJS and mongoDB as my backend service I want to get the date and time of the document when it is inserted in the collection.
This is what i am using :

```
 db.Users.find()._id.getTimestamp()
```

OUTPUT

```
 ISODate("2018-09-11T11:00:38Z")
```

Now, what I want to know is:

**1)**  Separate date and time from above string and convert it into readable format.

**2)**  This timestamp returned by MongoDB object id is based on server time or user's computer.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 2):

1) [`getTimestamp()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#getTimestamp) is available on `ObjectID` objects, like the `_id` field by default. So however you are getting your documents will have it available. This returns a javascript `Date` object, so its easy to extract and manipulate it how you need.

2) The embedded timestamp in the `ObjectID` is dependent on where it was created. If it was created client-side, it'll be from the client system; if it was created server-side, it'll be from the server system.

Comment: Your first point is cleared to me but in 2nd point how can i set timestamp on server side please let me know.

Comment: the only way I know of is the defaulted-`_id` field, if you create a document without an `_id` field, the server will generate it for you.

Comment: So how can i get time based on _id field.

Comment: in nodejs, if you have a `document` retrieved from mongo, you just do `document._id.getTimestamp()`

Comment: I have document like this {"_id":ObjectId("as244fgv....."),"Name": "Digi"}.So how can i get timestamp for this document.Please let me know .

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I can be any more clear. Get your document by normal means and do `your_document._id.getTimestamp()`

Answer (score 2):

1-

```
.getTimestamp().toLocaleDateString() //get the date
  .getTimestamp().toLocaleTimeString() // get the time
```

2-Internally, Date objects are stored as a signed 64-bit integer representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970).
  One standard way that many databases store dates is as a count of milliseconds since the Epoch, with 0 representing January 1, 1970 at 00:00:00GMT. This is how dates are stored internally in **most programming languages**.